# Minimum polynomial of $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{5}$ above $\mathbb{Q}$ (and a generalization)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

I have found that $\alpha = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{5}$ is a root of $f(x) = x^6-6x^4-10x^3+12x^2-60x+17$. I don't know if this is the minimum polynomial of $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{5}$ above $\mathbb{Q}$.
I have found also that $[(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha))(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]=3$. This may it help.
I have tried to prove that $f(x)$ is irreducible above $\mathbb{Q}$ or also to prove that $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ but I haven't been able to do it.
Do you know how to do it?

Generalization:
The problem will be solved if $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) = (\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}))(\sqrt[3]{5})$. Is this always true for every couple of radicals?

Foot note: a question very similar to this has already been asked, but without solution, here the old thread [Degree of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{5}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8409/degree-of-sqrt2-sqrt35-over-mathbbq-sqrt2-and-mathbbq-sq)

Comment: It should be 'over $\mathbb Q$', not 'above'. Since you know that $[(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha))(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]=3$, you're almost done. You know that $\alpha$ is a root of $f(t)$. What does this tell you about the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb Q$? You also know that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=2$.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, I am still improving my technical English.

Comment: Regarding the problem, I know that $[(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha))(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}]$ is 6, but this do not solve my problem.

Comment: $f(x)$ would be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ iff $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) =  (\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}))(\sqrt[3]{5})$

Comment: I'm not sure if that's always the case but one way to find the minimal polynomial is by taking linear combinations of different powers of $\alpha$ with an undetermined coefficient in front of each term (and no coefficient in front of the highest power term as to make it minimal) and then setting that equal to $0$ and solving for the coefficients. The smallest degree of $\alpha$ for which this can be done forms the minimal polynomial.

Comment: "I know that $[(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha))(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}]$ is 6". Typo? If it is a typo: ah, sorry. Completely missed that. You need to use the [primitive element theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem). You will find that $\mathbb Q(\alpha)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2, \root 3\of 5)$.

Comment: This the kind of "generalization" I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: I have read something about th primitive element theorem. It states that exist two rational number $q_1, q_2$ that satisfy the condition $(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt[3]{5})=\mathbb{Q}(q_1\sqrt{2}+q_2\sqrt[3]{5})$. So it is not obvious that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt[3]{5})$.

Comment: How can you state it?

Comment: @user3343783 You should use the ping feature (`@NameOfThePerson message`). I had no idea you had messaged me, I came back by chance. There are just a few restrictions on $q_1$ and $q_2$, (see the proof). You can probably see that $q_1=q_2=1$ work out well.

Answer (score 5):

I kind of wonder how you found this polynomial, that must have been quite some work. Let me show you an alternative way. Let $\zeta$ be a $3$rd unit root. Then we examine the Galois extension
$$
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{5},\zeta)
$$
of degree $2\cdot3\cdot 2 = 12$. This is Galois, as any automorphism must send $\sqrt{2}$ to either itself or $-\sqrt{2}$ and it must permutate the roots of $X^3-\sqrt[3]{5}$, giving us $2\cdot 3! = 12$ automorphisms. Now the minimal polynomial equals the polynomial whose roots are those elements that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{5}$ can be mapped to by elements of the Galois group. In this case we get that the minimal polynomial equals
$$
(X-(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{5}))(X-(\sqrt{2} + \zeta\sqrt[3]{5}))(X-(\sqrt{2} + \zeta^2\sqrt[3]{5}))(X-(-\sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{5}))(X-(-\sqrt{2} + \zeta\sqrt[3]{5}))(X-(-\sqrt{2} + \zeta^2\sqrt[3]{5})).
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know Galois Theory yet so I will study it in order to understand  solution.