# Determine the minimal polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field

> Determine the minimal polynomial of $v=\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{2}$ over $\mathbb Q[x]$.

Can't find the right calculations. I am trying to find another way. I know the minimum polynomial of  $w=\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}$ but still that does not  help. I know it must be of degree 6 since the field extension of $\sqrt{3}$ + $\sqrt[3]{2}$ has degree 6.

Comment: You might find this answer helpful if you already know a bit of Galois theory: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825884/minimum-polynomial-of-sqrt2-sqrt35-above-mathbbq-and-a-general/825900#825900. Otherwise, there's not much you can do other than get your hands dirty with the algebra: start computing powers of $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{2}$ and observe linear dependencies once you get to degree 6. Showing irreducibility isn't so easy, but the comments on this question give some insight there: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8409/degree-of-sqrt2-sqrt35-over-mathbbq-sqrt2-and-mathbbq-sq

Comment: It is an exercise on fields extension im supposed to solve it without galois theory..

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis How do you know the field extension is of degree 6?

Comment: you can check that is the same field extension as $Q(\sqrt{3},\sqrt[3]{2})$ which has a degree 6 which you can prove with the "tower" theorem and some number theory.

Comment: That $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3,\sqrt[3]{2}):\mathbb Q]=6$ I can understand, but why $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3,\sqrt[3]{2})=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3+\sqrt[3]{2})$? (This seems a much more difficult job than finding a polynomial from $\mathbb Z[X]$ having $\sqrt 3+\sqrt[3]{2}$ as a root. Surprisingly, you claim that managed the hard job, but had troubles with the easy part.)

Comment: You are right it needs a lot of computation.I tried finding the inverse of $(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{2})$ and expand then try find a combination of $(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{2})$ raised to a power  and add or substract the inverse  so  im left with just one of those 2 but needs alot of computations.I was sure they are the same  just by intuition and that it it seemed to me that there must exist combinations that can prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the cube of both sides $v-\sqrt{3}=\sqrt[3]{2}$

$v^3-3v^2\sqrt{3}+9v-3\sqrt{3}=2$

We factorize: $3\sqrt{3}(v^2+1)=v^3+9v-2$.

A last squaring of both sides get rid of the last square root:

$27(v^4+2v^2+1)=v^6+81v^2+4+18v^4-36v-4v^3$

or:

$v^6 - 9\,v^4   - 4\,v^3 + 27\,v^2- 36\,v  -23  = 0$

The left hand side is the minimal polynomial.

Comment: ohhh that was easy  i should have isolated the cube first such an idiot