# Determine the Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

> Let $L:=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{5})$. How to determine $[L:\mathbb{Q}]$ and $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$?

I thought about showing $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{5})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt[3]{5})$ first.

It's $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{5} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt[3]{5}) \Rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{5})\subset\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt[3]{5})$

The other direction

$(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{5})^2=3+2\sqrt{3}\sqrt[3]{5}+(\sqrt[3]{5})^2$

Here I don't see what to do next. What has to be done now?

Comment: For the degree see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825884/minimum-polynomial-of-sqrt2-sqrt35-above-mathbbq-and-a-general?rq=1). Just replace $\sqrt{2}$ by $\sqrt{3}$ in the solution.